# Is there a way to take a ECS TaskDefinition as an input to a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am new to AWS CloudFormation. I have been testing out automating deployments of containers using this service. However, as of now, I am manually adding the name of my TaskDefinition to the YAML file of the CloudFormation template. Is there a way for me to define this as an input.

Comment: You can define the actual taskdefinition in the template.

Comment: True, but I want to be able to do that dynamically whenever I use the stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use stack output exports, define export value on one stack and import it in any other: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html

Comment: Is this what people mean when they say "nested stacks"?

Comment: No, that's separate thing, unrelated to general export of value. Article I linked explains what a nested stack is and what's the difference between the two.